# JAXB with JDK7 Issue - com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a JAXB marshal code that runs fine with Java 1.6 for an object. But when i run with Java 1.7 Runtime, i am getting the below error. Below is the error. At a high level, are there any known issues with JAXB having issues with Java 1.7. Please advise

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
       this problem is related to the following location:
              at java.util.List
              at protected com.models.util.ServiceMap com.models.MessageEvent.serviceMap
              at com.models.MessageEvent

       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:451)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:283)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1148)
       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:130)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445)
       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
```

Comment: Do you have a domain object that implements `List` or your own `List` implementation?  Can you post the corresponding part of your object model?

Answer (score 1):

It looks very tricky somehow. This issue was fixed sometime ago and the solution was that the below jaxb jars were not added to the build classpath because of the scope of maven dependency jar was given as "provided" and the scope tag was removed which will default to "compile".

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
```